# Can't configure a value for "network_interface": its value will be decided │ automatically based on the result of applying this configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I want to craete private endpoint with Network Interface in terraform. This is my terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "generic_kv_nic" {
  name                = "generic-${local.key_vault_name}-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.generic_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generic_kv_pe" {
  name                = "generic-${local.key_vault_name}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.generic_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "generic-${local.key_vault_name}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.generic_kv.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  network_interface {
    id = azurerm_network_interface.generic_kv_nic.id
  }

  depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_key_vault.generic_kv,
    azurerm_network_interface.generic_kv_nic
  ]
}
```

The error i get during `plan`:

```bash
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with azurerm_private_endpoint.imco_kv_pe,
│   on main.tf line 170, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generic_kv_pe":
│  170: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generic_kv_pe" {
│
│ Can't configure a value for "network_interface": its value will be decided
│ automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
```

How to overcome that issue?

Comment: Based on the documentation, the `network_interface` block is what you get when you create the resource. Try without the `network_interface` block.

Comment: @MarkoE which documentation? Can you share a link or probably the answer?

Comment: I don't have a way to test, but [attributes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint#attributes-reference) are available only after a resource is created. That's how I know it shouldn't be used as an argument.

Comment: hmm, so then how to connect network interface to private endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `azurerm_private_endpoint` resource creates a network interface itself, you don't need to explicitly create one and pass it in. The `network_interface` block is exported by the resource, i.e. it's an output of the resource, not an input you can set.

Get rid of the `azurerm_network_interface` resource and the `network_interface` block from your `azurerm_private_endpoint` resource.

You need to add the `subresource_names` argument to your `private_service_connection` block (`vault` in your case as the target resource is a Key Vault).

Also both of the dependencies listed in your `depends_on` block aren't needed because they're already implicit dependencies (due to you referencing those resources in the config for your `azurerm_private_endpoint`).

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generic_kv_pe" {
  name                = "generic-${local.key_vault_name}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.generic_net_rg.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.generic_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "generic-${local.key_vault_name}-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.generic_kv.id
    subresource_names              = ["vault"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! WIll test it soon. But the thing is that i want to attach a custom name to NIC, is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the AzureRM Terraform provider, but you may be able to do it by provisioning your Private Endpoint with the AzAPI Terraform provider (thin wrapper around the ARM REST APIs) and setting the `customNetworkInterfaceName` on the request payload, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/privateendpoints?pivots=deployment-language-terraform

Comment: it is, there is a property in private_endpoint resource, "custom_network_interface_name"

Comment: Sounds like you're in luck then :)